# finding parameters so that ∞ - ∞ = 0

Tags: limits, infinity

I am currently doing some old math exams and was wondering whether my solution for the given question was appropriate (see picture)

[image: see problem here]

for me it just feels like the point where I put together both limits bc the functions are continous I am doing something wrong, especially because the problem explicitly does not have a limit in front of the summand given by β*e^x+γ

Really appreciate your help guys, and sorry I am not yet able to write in LaTex.

Comment: Maybe work on your redaction, begin by stating "let us take $\beta,\gamma \in \dots$" if you give that you'll probably not score any points, the answer is correct but the reasoning is not

Comment: You're supposed to keep everything in the same limit then divide by $e^{2x}$

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{2e^{3x}}{e^{2x}-1}-\beta e^x +\gamma \right)=0 $$
Find the common denominator of your expression:
$$\frac{2e^{3x}-\beta e^{3x}+\beta e^x+\gamma e^{2x}-\gamma}{e^{2x}-1} $$
If $2-\beta\neq0$, the limit it $+\infty$ since $e^{3x}$ grows faster than $e^{2x}$; so you must have $\beta=2$.

If $\gamma\neq0$, the limit is $\gamma$ , hence you must have $\gamma=0.$